# To implemennt the checkbox for customized listview

Tags: android, database, listview, checkbox

I have written the code to get the values from the database and bind that values to listview.For that I have used the customized listview now according to requirement I want the checkbox for my each item of the list.How to do that

```
image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        note=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.note);
        tick=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.tick);
        cross=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cross);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("photooo");
        image.setImageBitmap(photo);
        if(photo!=null)
        {
            dbHelper = new RecordsDbAdapter(this);
            dbHelper.open();
            displayListView();
        }

    }
    private void displayListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_BIRTHDAY,

        };
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.name,
                R.id.birthdate,
        };
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like you had done before go to the XML file of R.layout.row and put this code:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="checkbox" />
```

and then edit your code like this:--

```
    private void displayListView() {
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
            RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_BIRTHDAY,
            RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_CHECKBOX

    };
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.name,
            R.id.birthdate,
            R.id.checkbox
    };
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.row,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- using LayoutInflater   add check box to list view
- after using SetTag methode  add  Tagvalue  to checkbox
- This tagvalue separate checkbox in  every item in listview
  following code example:`

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

```
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home1, null);
```

ViewHolder   holder1 = new ViewHolder();
holder1.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

```
   holder1.ch=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
  holder1.ch .setTag(position);
```